# Assigning a Unique ID to List Entries Based on other Columns

Tags: 2010, guid

So here's the set up; I've got a list with a bunch of columns (Task ID, Task Description, Project, Start Date). It's being used as an action tracker where anyone can choose to add an item and a form will pop up. Project is a choice type column. Currently we are assigning the Task ID number manually using the format Project.FY16.1.

We want the Task ID to automatically generate but the twist is we want each project to increment separately.

**For example**, Lets say we have project ABC and project DEF.

We would want the first entry for project ABC to have the Task ID ABC.FY16.1and the second entry for project ABC to have Task ID ABC.FY16.2
but when the first task for DEF gets entered we want the Task ID to be DEF.FY16.1

So far the closest I've gotten is creating a calculated column using

`=Project&"."&[Fiscal Year]&"."&ID`

Comment: Adding &ID will not generate the TaskID as you wanted

Comment: Search for unique ID and related words, plenty written about this

Comment: Based on what you're wanting to do, you'll need custom code to do this. Most likely in an Event Receiver ItemAdded function.

Comment: @DannyEngelman I haven't found any articles about how to increment based on another column in the list. I figured out how to do it if I just have it increment with each addition to the list but since I want it to start at one for each project I'm having difficulty.